# execute href before javascript toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link I call using jquery. I call the CSS class and it is a simple toggle show/hide feature. Problem I have having is the toggle is working before the `<a href>` is execute and not redirecting.

```
$(".second").click(function() { 
$("#img_close").toggle();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="img_close">
<a href="javascript:$.pageslide.close()" class="second"><img src="img/arrow.png"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#img_close { position:absolute; left:0px; display:none; top:50%; z-index:8888;}
```

`.second` is not redirecting the `javascript:$.pageslide.close()` because it toggles first, is there a way with jquery to fix this so it both executes the `a href` and the toggle?

Comment: Nope, there is not! Once the redirect happens, your javascript is lost. There is of course always a way, like adding something to the URL you're redirecting to so as to know what elements to toggle etc.

Comment: @andeno, so it is literally impossible to achieve both a toggle and send the link? could you fiddle an alternative? I thought it could be done? maybe with a time executing the toggle after the href has been sent?

Comment: on a second note, why is this an `<a>` at all? Why are you not using an `onclick` on the image instead, since this is not a link anchor in the slightest, but a javascript trigger?

Comment: I probably did'nt get it? You're not trying to redirect to another page, but just execute some javascript when someone clicks the anchor ?

Comment: @adeneo yes correct. I need `.second` to execute the javascript and the toggle at the same. So they both execute their purposes when clicked. IE: toggle hides `ìmg_close`and executes `javascript:$.pageslide.close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just put the two functions in the jquery function like this:

```
$(".second").click(function() { 
    $("#img_close").toggle();
    $.pageslide.close();
});
```

or instead of using `.click(function ());` you use `.bind("click",function());`

either or should work